# New GHC8 and implicit parameters

Tags: haskell, typeclass, implicit

In his [implicit configuration paper](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/tr-15-04.pdf), Oleg reflect values at the type level.

With the new tools of GHC8, what can be improved to his presentation ?
For instance we can remove the use of undefined with type application, but what else ?

Here is the original after the intro

```
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-9.2 script --package http-conduit --package tagged --package lens
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForAll      #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-unused-imports -fno-warn-unused-local-binds  -fno-warn-missing-signatures #-}

import Prelude
import Control.Lens.Operators ((<&>))
import Data.Function
import Data.Kind
```

code

```
-- Original
--------------
data Zero; data Twice (s :: Type); data Succ (s :: Type); data Pred (s :: Type) -- pure type

class ReflectNum1 s where reflectNum1 :: Num a => s -> a

instance ReflectNum1 Zero      where reflectNum1 _ = 0 -- on ne se sert pas de s
instance ReflectNum1 s => ReflectNum1 (Twice s) where reflectNum1 _ = (reflectNum1 (undefined :: s) * 2)
instance ReflectNum1 s => ReflectNum1 (Succ s ) where reflectNum1 _ = (reflectNum1 (undefined :: s) + 1)
instance ReflectNum1 s => ReflectNum1 (Pred s ) where reflectNum1 _ = (reflectNum1 (undefined :: s) - 1)

--
v1 :: Int = reflectNum1 (undefined :: Zero)
```

with type application we can have a nice cleaning of the undefined

```
--- Type Application

-- outillage
newtype Tagged s a = Tagged { unTag :: a } deriving Show
deriving instance Functor (Tagged s)
instance Applicative (Tagged s) where
  pure = Tagged
  Tagged f <*> Tagged x = Tagged (f x)
  _ *> n = n

retag :: Tagged s b -> Tagged t b
retag = Tagged . unTag

class ReflectNum s where reflectNum :: Num a => Tagged s a
instance                 ReflectNum  Zero     where reflectNum = Tagged 0
instance ReflectNum s => ReflectNum (Pred  s) where reflectNum = (reflectNum @ s) <&> ((-) 1) & retag
instance ReflectNum s => ReflectNum (Succ  s) where reflectNum = (reflectNum @ s) <&> ((+) 1) & retag
instance ReflectNum s => ReflectNum (Twice s) where reflectNum = (reflectNum @ s) <&> (* 2)   & retag

getReflNum :: forall s a. (ReflectNum s, Num a) => a
getReflNum = unTag (reflectNum @ s)
v3 :: Int = getReflNum  @ Zero
```

Can we do better ? As in expressing more properties, or in a nicer way ?

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection-2.1.2/docs/Data-Reflection.html

Comment: [The implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection-2.1.2/docs/src/Data-Reflection.html#reify) is ... is it beautiful?  Is it awful?

Comment: @melpomene oh thank you !